# How to read android:src in my custom component

Tags: android, custom-component

I am trying to create a custom component which inherits from RelativeLayout.

In my xml layout file, I have:

```
<Mycomponent 
    android:src="@drawable/my_test_image">
      <TestView>
</Mycomponent>
```

My question is how can I create a Drawable class in the constructor of Mycomponent?

I have tried to read the source code of ImageView, but it seems tried to some android Internal.R .

Is there anyway I can do that in my code.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to get the drawable `my_test_image` in the custom view's constructor?

Comment: Yes. I want to create a Drawable object by reading the 'android:src' in the layout xml file.

Answer (score 16):

I think Luksprog it's wrong, I have an easy solution to access you custom component "src" data without styleable, just calling the AttributeSet:

> attrs.getAttributeResourceValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android",
>   "src", 0);

Here you can see my example to make bitmaps size more cheap, jeje.

```
public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
 super(context, attrs);
 int src_resource = attrs.getAttributeResourceValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", "src", 0);
 this.setImageBitmap(getDrawable(getResources(),src_resource));
}

public static Bitmap getDrawable(Resources res, int id){
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(res.openRawResource(id));
}
```

Now you will have something in the xml like this:

```
<com.example.com.jfcogato.mycomponent.CustomView
    android:id="@+id/tAImageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:src="@drawable/big_image_example"/>
```

Comment: `this.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(src_resource))`
... should be used to support drawables of all types.  Your code only supports images.

Answer (score 1):

I've also seen suggestions that you can do this...

```
    int attributeIds[] = { android.R.attr.src };
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attributeIds);
    int resourceId = a.getResourceId(0, 0);
    a.recycle();
```

In my experience this code compiles but returns 0 at runtime.

So yeah... go with jfcogato's answer above.